# get contact event details in android

Tags: android, cursor, android-contacts

I need to fetch the all events of all contacts in my android application.

Can anyone help me on this?
 what I need to place the Uri for the below..

```
Cursor events = getContentResolver().query(xxxx,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
```

Comment: @dilaraates what you have edited there?

Comment: I add new tag "cursor" :D when you add tag related about your question or code maybe more people will interest your question.

Comment: @dilaraates do you know the solution?

Comment: Actually I do not know. I help to you to find someone who knows the solution but maybe you can examine this question. It will help you to solve the problem--<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009309/android-getcontentresolver-query-error

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, it should work. Do the `Log.d(tag, "Output here");` to test your output, but it should work. It does here.

```
public void getEvent(String contactId)
    {
        final String[] projection = new String[] {
                Event.CONTACT_ID,
                Event.START_DATE,
                //Event.TYPE,
                Event.LABEL
        };

        final String filter = Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " + Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? ";
        final String parameters[] = {Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, contactId};

        Cursor cursor =  context.getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                    projection, 
                    filter, 
                    parameters,
                    null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                final String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Event.CONTACT_ID));
                final String startDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Event.START_DATE));
                //final String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Event.TYPE));
                final String label = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Event.LABEL));
            }
        }

    }
```